# Calculating Named Ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

The spreadsheet contains numerous named ranges. I need to refer to those ranges using `VLOOKUP`. Here's the kicker, I want to refer to the ranges via a text manipulation. Case.  Column A contains list of short dates:

- JAN 2003
- MAR 2003
- FEB 2003

The named ranges are

- JAN2003
- FEB2003
- etc.

I want to refer to the named ranges within `VLOOKUP` as `VLOOKUP("net",JAN2003,2,False)`.  Simple enough; I can set this up and it works fine. But when I try to refer to `JAN2003` via a text operation on the Column A list, I get errors.

Instead of the above `VLOOKUP` formula, I try to use: `VLOOKUP("net", LEFT(A4,3)&RIGHT(A4,4),2,False)`. This produces a #N/A error. The text manipulation returns JAN2003 (the named range) when used separately, but error when used in the `VLOOKUP` formula.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wtf, if you mean excel, say excel

Comment: That won't work because FEB 2013 as a short date is read as 41306 by Excel, so no match. I don't have time to answer at the moment but try researching `INDERECT`, that may help

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the `#N/A!` because the second argument of the `VLOOKUP` function should be a range, not a string. To get around this, you need to wrap the formula for the name of the range in an `INDIRECT` function.

```
=VLOOKUP("net",INDIRECT(LEFT(A4,3)&RIGHT(A4,4)),2,False)
```

`INDIRECT` converts a textual reference to a range into an Excel range reference.

[More information on INDIRECT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx)